# I want to put this long sentence in a short form by removing the repetition

Tags: meaning, synonyms, syntactic-analysis, sentence

The X robot can go to places that the Y robot cannot reach, and the Y robot can go to places that the X robot cannot reach.

Comment: The X robot can go to places that the Y robot cannot reach, and vice versa?

Comment: Each of the two robots can go to places that the other robot cannot go to.

Comment: The robots have different abilities.

Comment: The X and Y robots can both go to places inaccessible to the other.

Comment: Each robot has its own private area. PS: Aren't answers in comment discouraged here?

Comment: This is a short question and kind of the proof-reading question like. However I will take a stab. "Both robots can go to places unreachable to the other."

Answer (score 1):

Both robots can go to places the other can’t reach.

Comment: I would go wit *Each* robot.